# Boost::bind a method with boost::function parameter

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I would like to provide an extra boost::function to a async_write. I want the connections own HandleWrite function to be called first and then call the provided boost::function.

Member method of Connection that binds to asio async_write

> ```
> void Connection::HandleWrite(
>     const boost::system::error_code& e,
>     boost::function<void (const boost::system::error_code&)> handler)
>  {
>     // Code removed for clarity
>
>     if(!handler.empty())
>         handler(e);
>  };
> ```

Trying to bind HandleWrite to a asio async_write and provide another bind as the value for handler. This doesn't compile. What am I doing wrong?

> ```
>   void Connection::QueueRequest(
>       boost::shared_array<char> message, 
>       std::size_t size, 
>       boost::function<void (const boost::system::error_code&)> handler)
>   {
>      // Code hidden for clarity
>
>      boost::asio::async_write(m_Socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
>          boost::bind(&Connection::HandleWrite, shared_from_this(),
>             boost::asio::placeholders::error,
>             handler
>          )
>      );
>   }
> ```

The error message I get from the compiler is the following:

> ```
> Error 1   error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    boost\bind\bind.hpp 69
> Error   2   error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''    boost\bind\bind.hpp 69
> Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'    boost\bind\bind.hpp 69
> Error   4   error C2208: 'boost::_bi::type' : no members defined using this type    boost\bind\bind.hpp 69
> Error   5   fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   boost\bind\bind.hpp 69
> ```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided the error message

Comment: I have no added the error message above.

Comment: The problem turned out to be in another place that used the same HandleWrite function and wasn't bound correctly. After fixing that it compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in another place that used the same HandleWrite function and wasn't bound correctly. After fixing that it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

What error(s) are you getting exactly? I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code shown in your question, so I can't give you a direct answer.

However, Kornel's answer made me doubt, as I thought that the functors generated by boost::bind can take any number of arguments and simply ignore the extra ones.

So I quickly hacked this to verify:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void Foo(const boost::system::error_code&)
{
    // whatever
}

struct Client : boost::enable_shared_from_this<Client>
{
    void HandleWrite(
        const boost::system::error_code& Err, 
        boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> OtherHandler
    )
    {
        std::cout << "MyHandler(" << Err << ")\n";
        OtherHandler(Err);
    }

    void MakeTheCall(boost::function<void (const boost::system::error_code&)> Other)
    {
        using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

        // Of course, the scope and initialization of
        // io_service, sock and request are all wrong here,
        // as we're only interested in testing if the async_write
        // call below will compile.
        // Don't try to run this at home!
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::socket sock(io_service);
        boost::asio::streambuf request;

        boost::asio::async_write(sock, request,
            boost::bind(&Client::HandleWrite, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                Other
            )
        );
    }
};


int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Client> c;
    c->MakeTheCall(boost::bind(&Foo, _1));

    return 0;
}
```

which is sketching what I guess you're trying to do.

As expected, it does compile, so comparing it with what you're actually doing may help you finding the problem.